# Javascript lodash flatten hierarchical object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, lodash

I have hierarchical json. I want to flatten it.
This is my json:

```js
{
  "id": "111",
  "name": "v5",
  "define": {
    "system": "abc",
    "concept": [{
      "code": "y7",
      "concept": [{
        "code": "AGG",
        "display": "Abcess"
      }, {
        "code": "ABS",
        "display": "Abcess"
      }]
    }, {
      "code": "y8",
      "concept": [{
        "code": "AGc",
        "display": "ccc"
      }, {
        "code": "hjj",
        "display": "uii"
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```

Is there a way in `lodash`, to flatten this json to array of "code, display" only?

If no, is there another library that can do it?
Thanks.

For example of result:

```js
[{
  "code": "AGG",
  "display": "Abcess"
}, {
  "code": "ABS",
  "display": "Abcess"
}, {
  "code": "AGc",
  "display": "ccc"
}, {
  "code": "hjj",
  "display": "uii"
}]
```

Comment: "If no, is there another library that can do it?". Asking for off-site resources is not allowed on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way in lodash, to flatten this json to array of "code,
>   desplay" only?

You mean concatenate all `concept` childs?

Try this

```js
var obj = {
  "id": "111",
  "name": "v5",
  "define": {
    "system": "abc",
    "concept": [{
      "code": "y7",
      "concept": [{
        "code": "AGG",
        "display": "Abcess"
      }, {
        "code": "ABS",
        "display": "Abcess"
      }]
    }, {
      "code": "y8",
      "concept": [{
        "code": "AGc",
        "display": "ccc"
      }, {
        "code": "hjj",
        "display": "uii"
      }]
    }]
  }
}

var output = [];

obj.define.concept.forEach(function(o) {
  output = output.concat(o.concept)
});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(output, 0, 4) + "</pre>");
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
var data = { "id": "111", "name": "v5", "define": { "system": "abc", "concept": [{ "code": "y7", "concept": [{ "code": "AGG", "display": "Abcess" }, { "code": "ABS", "display": "Abcess" }] }, { "code": "y8", "concept": [{ "code": "AGc", "display": "ccc" }, { "code": "hjj", "display": "uii" }] }] } },
    flat = function (array) {
        var r = [];
        array.forEach(function (a) {
            a.concept.forEach(function (b) {
                r.push(b);
            });
        });
        return r;
    }(data.define.concept);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(flat, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```